# Reading message content and Message sender?

Tags: android, sms, message

I'm Building an application that will **read every new sms from inbox** 
and it is from **specific sender**, my app will read the content and if it has some specific content then it will do some action.

**Goals :**

**1.** I want to get new message sender's name or number (say my specific sender don't show number it is something like `TM-Google , TM-MyGinger` mostly **telemarketting Senders**)

**2.** If it is from one for whom i was searching then i want to read the content of message.
       The else is my part.
    Please provide some idea or code snippet.

Comment: what u have tried for listening every sms and u need to use ContentObserver for watching   inbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a SMS receiver

```
    public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];

                // getting SMS information from Pdu.
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                }

                for (SmsMessage currentMessage : messages) {
                    // currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress()   has sender's phone number
                    // currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody()     has the actual message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read inbox using following code:

```
Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
            Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
                    mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                    new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date",
                            "body", "type" }, null, null, null);
             startManagingCursor(cursor1);
            String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body",
                    "type" };
            if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
                String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
                Log.e("Count",count);
                while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
                    String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                    String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
                    String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
                    String msg = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
                    String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
                    et.setText( et.getText() + "Address:" + address + "\n"
                            + "Name:" + name + "\n"
                            + "Date:" + date + "\n"
                            + "MSG:" + msg + "\n"
                            + "type:" + type + "\n"
                            );



               }
           }
```

Add flowing to manifest

```
<receiver android:name="SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

and add permission for `READ_SMS` and `RECEIVE_SMS`

Comment: weather it will be able to read the sender address which are not in number form

Comment: Yes. If sender is `TM-MyGinger` the address returns 'TM-MyGinger'

Comment: I'm too busy please bear with me i will do it soon

Comment: I've started this project but its pending i'll do it soon thanks

Comment: Reading the sms from inbox requires android.permission.READ_SMS